# How to move many files by type using Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to move multiple files from one location to another using Node.js without using imported 3rd part modules (been trying with fs.rename). Similar function on cmd to `move *.txt c:\Users\Me\Documents`

> Using this works perfectly moving one file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.rename('./text.txt', './dir/text.txt', err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Move complete!');
})
```

> However, I want to move all files without 3rd party modules or
>   building a JSON object. Is it possible? My thoughts something like
>   this(documentation states arguments 1 and 2 need to be strings):

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.rename(./*.txt, ./dir/*.txt, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Move complete!');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Read all files from the directory and check the file extension & move them one by one using loop.

**Sample Code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readdir('<PATH>', (err, files) => {

  files.forEach(file => {
     if (path.extname(file) === '.txt') {
           fs.rename(file, '<NEW_PATH>', err => {
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log('Moving ' + file);  
           });
     }

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`fs.rename()` only works on a single file. In order to move several files, you must write the logic yourself. One way is to build a list of the files to move and then iterate over that list and `rename()` them one at a time.